# Checkpointing With NOT Serializable

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

Want to understand a basic issue. Here is my code:

```
def createStreamingContext(sparkCheckpointDir: String,batchDuration: Int ) = {

val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, Seconds(batchDuration))

ssc
}

val ssc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(sparkCheckpointDir, () => createStreamingContext(sparkCheckpointDir, batchDuration))


val inputDirectStream = EventHubsUtils.createDirectStreams(ssc,namespace,progressDir,Map(name -> eventhubParameters)).map(receivedRecord => new String(receivedRecord.getBody))


inputDirectStream.foreachRDD { (rdd: RDD[String], time: Time) =>
    val df = spark.read.json(rdd)
    df.show(truncate=false)

}

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

the above code works, and I can see the DF.

The issue is: If I enable check point by

```
def createStreamingContext(sparkCheckpointDir: String,batchDuration: Int ) = {

val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, Seconds(batchDuration))
ssc.checkpoint(sparkCheckpointDir)
ssc
}
```

Then the ssc.start() fails with "

> DStream checkpointing has been enabled but the DStreams with their
>   functions are not serializable"

What I am doing wrong? I want to process DF with checkpoint enabled.

Spark Version: version 2.0.2.2.5.4.2-7
Launch: spark-shell --jars spark-streaming-eventhubs_2.11-2.1.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

I think [Why is my Spark Streaming application throwing a NotSerializableException when I enable checkpointing?](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/382/why-is-my-spark-streaming-application-throwing-a-n.html) will solve your problem:

> If you enable checkpointing in Spark Streaming, then objects used in a function called in foreachRDD should be Serializable

Solutions:

> - Turn off checkpointing by removing the jssc.checkpoint line.
> - Make the object being used Serializable.
> - Declare NotSerializable inside the forEachRDD function, so the following code sample would be fine:

In your code, what is the `EventHubsUtils.createDirectStreams()` doing ? maybe you can make it serializable.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have read the link you suggested. EventHubsUtils.createDirectStreams is Direct Dstream creation for event hub. How can I make it serializable?

Comment: Maybe you can have a try `extends Serializable `?

Answer (score 0):

You can try transforming the `Dstream[EventHub]` to `Dstream of type scala/java primitives` as serialization and deserialization is handled by spark. 
You are facing this serialization error because in `forEachRDD` you are using the "show" action. 
This action is pulling the data from executor to driver over the wire and this requires serialization. You can convert it to `Dstream of scala/java type` (like `Dstream[Tuple*]` which would suit your case) and map each attribute in your `EventHub` object to a tuple element.